# With Excel vba, save web image to disk

Tags: image, vba, excel, save

I am trying to save an image from a webpage using excel vba.
I'm managed to get the string (although not the one I want), and need to save it to disk.

The HTML code for the source is:

```
<img id="SkuPageMainImg" data-sku="491215" alt="Papir ubleket kraft 60g 40cm 5kg/rull" class="skuImageSTD" src="/content/images/product/491215_1_xnm.jpg?v=4TWLBni1V4k8GV8B_0P-GA" data-zoomimage="//www.staples.no/content/images/product/491215_1_xnl.jpg" data-resizeimage="{&quot;0to1024&quot;:&quot;/content/images/product/491215_1_xnm.jpg?v=4TWLBni1V4k8GV8B_0P-GA&quot;,&quot;1025to1450&quot;:&quot;//www.staples.no/content/images/product/491215_1&quot;}" data-screensize="">
```

My code is: `IMG = .document.getElementById("SkuPageMainImg").src`

This code captures the url after the `src=` :

```
/content/images/product/491215_1_xnm.jpg?v=4TWLBni1V4k8GV8B_0P-GA"
```

This will do, but what i would preffer to catch is the url after `data-zoomimage=` :
`"//www.staples.no/content/images/product/491215_1_xnl.jpg"`

Either way, what I am looking to accomplish is having Excel VBA save the image to a file on my disk - typically `c:\folder\image_name.jpg`

Anybody know the code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the URLDownloadToFile function and use it directly. The following is an entire module code sheet, including the declarations section at the top. The routine expects a list of the full img src URLs in column A starting at row 2. e.g.: http://www.staples.no/content/images/product/491215_1_xnm.jpg

[image: Image list for download]

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#End If

Public Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000

Sub dlStaplesImages()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, ret As Long, sIMGDIR As String, sWAN As String, sLAN As String

    sIMGDIR = "c:\folder"
    If Dir(sIMGDIR, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sIMGDIR

    With ActiveSheet    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To lr

            sWAN = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
            sLAN = sIMGDIR & Chr(92) & Trim(Right(Replace(sWAN, Chr(47), Space(999)), 999))

            Debug.Print sWAN
            Debug.Print sLAN

            If CBool(Len(Dir(sLAN))) Then
                Call DeleteUrlCacheEntry(sLAN)
                Kill sLAN
            End If

            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sWAN, sLAN, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&)

            .Cells(rw, 2) = ret
            Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

A value of 0 is column B indicates success (e.g. ERROR_SUCCESS).

[image: Image download folder]

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a dream.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, i know this is an old post, but i am facing same issue with downloading pictures from URL.
I am using your code, but consistently get error "**-2146697208** in B column. I have used your sample URL too, but it also results in the same error. What could go wrong?