# Excel VBA error type '13' typemismatch

Tags: excel, types, error-handling, type-mismatch, vba

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#End If

Public Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000

    'Global Variables for passing values b/w subs
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim folderLocation As Variant





Sub airtableCleaner()
    Dim argCounter As Integer
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String
    Dim shellCommand As String

    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Example C:/downloads
    myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'Example C:/downloads/book1.csv

    'Ask user if they want to run macro
    Answer = MsgBox("Run? Airtable - 1: primaryKey, 2: one image attachment", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")
    If Answer = vbYes Then

    folderLocation = Application.InputBox("Give a subfolder name for directory. E.G. Batch1")

    'Creates new folder based on input
    Dim strDir As String
    strDir = folderPath & "\" & folderLocation

    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strDir
    Else
        MsgBox "Directory exists."
    End If

    'Cleanup to just amazons3 dl.airtable links
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="* ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    'Count Cells
    Range("B2").Activate
    Do
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        argCounter = argCounter + 1

    Loop

    'Copy Image Links to new cells to format in Column C
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Clean up links to only have names in Column C
    Selection.Replace What:="https://dl.airtable.com/", Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
    False, ReplaceFormat:=False


    'Cleanup Broken images using excelVBA downloader %5B1%5D = B1D
     Columns("C:C").Select
     Range("C40").Activate
     Selection.Replace What:="%5B1%5D", Replacement:="B1D", LookAt:=xlPart, _
     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
     ReplaceFormat:=False


    'Create Column D batch files           
        Range("D2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""COPY "",CHAR(34), " & folderPath & "\" & ", C2,CHAR(34),"" "", CHAR(34), " & _
                      Chr(34) & folderPath & "\" & folderLocation & "\" & Chr(34) & ",A2,"".png"",CHAR(34))"                              

    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & argCounter + 1)

    'Delete header row 1 information
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'Repaste values back into column D removing formulas
        Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Image downloader to source folder
    Call dlStaplesImages

    'Make the batch files using row data col D
    Call ExportRangetoBatch

    'Ask user to run bat file now or later
    shellCommand = """" & folderPath & "\" & "newcurl.bat" & """"
    Call Shell(shellCommand, vbNormalFocus)

    End If
End Sub

'https://superuser.com/questions/1045707/create-bat-file-with-excel-data-with-vba    , modified copypasta code

Sub ExportRangetoBatch()

    Dim ColumnNum: ColumnNum = 4   ' Column D
    Dim RowNum: RowNum = 1          ' Row to start on
    Dim objFSO, objFile

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(folderPath & "\newcurl.bat")    'Output Path

    Dim OutputString: OutputString = ""

    OutputString = "Timeout 3" & vbNewLine 'useful for error checking

    Do
        OutputString = OutputString & Replace(Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum).Value, Chr(10), vbNewLine) & vbNewLine 'Goes to new line in string, then creates another
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum))

    OutputString = OutputString & "Timeout 3"   'useful for errorchecking


    objFile.Write (OutputString)

    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub



'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359682/with-excel-vba-save-web-image-to-disk/31360105#31360105      , modified copypasta code

Sub dlStaplesImages()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, ret As Long, sIMGDIR As String, sWAN As String, sLAN As String

    sIMGDIR = folderPath
    'If Dir(sIMGDIR, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sIMGDIR

    With ActiveSheet    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 1 To lr 'rw to last row, assume first row is not header

            sWAN = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
            sLAN = sIMGDIR & Chr(92) & Trim(Right(Replace(sWAN, Chr(47), Space(999)), 999))

            Debug.Print sWAN
            Debug.Print sLAN

            If CBool(Len(Dir(sLAN))) Then
                Call DeleteUrlCacheEntry(sLAN)
                Kill sLAN
            End If

            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sWAN, sLAN, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&)

            'Imported code to output success / fail
            If ret = 0 Then
            Range("E" & rw).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            Range("E" & rw).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If

            '.Cells(rw, 5) = ret
            Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

I have this set of code. The above code works without any errors. Basically it takes some input data, transforms data, downloads images, and inputs a .batch file to rename many all the images after

The problem I have is when I change this line:

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""COPY "",CHAR(34),C2,CHAR(34),"" "", CHAR(34), " & _
                          Chr(34) & folderPath & "\" & folderLocation & "\" & Chr(34) & ",A2,"".png"",CHAR(34))"
```

to this new line:

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""COPY "",CHAR(34), " & folderPath & "\" & ", C2,CHAR(34),"" "", CHAR(34), " & _
                          Chr(34) & folderPath & "\" & folderLocation & "\" & Chr(34) & ",A2,"".png"",CHAR(34))"
```

I get an error here

> Run-time error '13' :Type mismatch

On this line where I run a do loop

```
OutputString = OutputString & Replace(Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum).Value, Chr(10), vbNewLine) & vbNewLine 'Goes to new line in string, then creates another
```

Originally, `OutputString` took iterative values like this:

`COPY "foo.png" "C:\batch\foo2.png"`

Now I am trying to give it this:

`COPY "C:\foo.png" "C:\batch\foo2.png"`

The only thing I changed was added a longer string value that `outputString` would have to be reading. I'm not sure why I have a type 13 error (variable datatypes not matching)

Comment: When the error happens, what precisely is Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum).Value ?

Comment: You don't put quotes around `folderPath` when building the formula, so you get the path unquoted in the resulting formula which leads to the `#NAME?` error in the cell which gives Type mismatch when you try to pass the error value to `Replace`. Please debug your code. It is not difficult to observe `#NAME?` in a cell or in the tooltip over `Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum).Value`.

Comment: Type Mismatch will raise if you try to combine a string and an error. Is there any reason you're not using more strongly-typed variables?  I would guess that possibly your `Replace` call is raising the error. Try isolating that statement in the *Immediate* pane or do a `MsgBox` to view it, and see if an error raises on that statement alone.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's syntax is really confusing when passing variables to excel-functions in VBA.

What happened was I was verbatim passing the the folderPath variable (e.g. C:\foo) right inside of an excel formula, when I should have been concatenating each result seperately (which was not possible with my previous solution)

So I just rewrote a set of clean code using no built in excel functions

Original code snippet causing Error type 13 code statement:

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""COPY "",CHAR(34), " & folderPath & "\" & ", C2,CHAR(34),"" "", CHAR(34), " & _
                          Chr(34) & folderPath & "\" & folderLocation & "\" & Chr(34) & ",A2,"".png"",CHAR(34))"
```

New Clean and easy-to-read / edit code:

```
For row = 2 To argCounter + 1
    A = Cells(row, 1).Value
    C = Cells(row, 3).Value

    A = """" & folderPath & "\" & folderLocation & "\" & A & ".png" & """"
    C = """" & folderPath & "\" & C & """"

    Cells(row, 4).Value = "Copy " & C & " " & A
Next row
```